# Fixed a background image with 100% scale to screen

Tags: html, css, mobile, background-image

Do anyone has similar experience and has the solution?

I use below CSS to display an background image on a mobile, of course I do declare

I could not able to display the image according to screen's height and width, if I remove the "background-attachment: fixed", then image is resized according to the screen's height and width but image is center according to the length of web content instead of the screen.

Do anyone have better solution?

```
#home {
  background: url('../images/hkfmpt_trans.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this with  background-size: cover;  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html { 
  background: url('../images/hkfmpt_trans.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: image could not fit to screen size and also not fix on the page, it scroll with text.

Comment: oh ya, wat do u want to do?maintain the aspect ratio and have the image fill the background?